# GCP - Multiple regions for same website and database

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have my API, DB and Frontend website all hosted on GCP in the 'Australia' region.

I'm now wanting to release my website to the United States. so i've mapped another domain name pointing to my website which will function slightly differently if the domain name is a .com as opposed to a .com.au.

Is it possible to replicate my API, DB and FE to a 'United states' region as well as the Australia region? Is it essentially the same website, so i'd rather not have to deploy multiple versions of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to have the same database? Or the US database is independent of the Australia db?

Comment: Could you please provide more details regarding current and target configuration? For instance is this a GKE-based setup? Do you want to expose existing web site to the US but deliver it's resources closer to the end users, or create a full clone on top of independent computing capacity in US region?

Comment: Yeah I want it to use the same database and all the same resources. It’s built using GAE. Essentially I’d like the same website, resources and dB to be replicated in 2 regions so it’s closer to the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since App Engine links itself to a location, you are not going to be able to move it to a different region. You would need to create a new project in which you can deploy a copy of your application but in a region closer to your customers in order to diminish their latency.

If your database is on Cloud SQL, there is no issue with you having multiple App Engine projects connecting to a central Cloud SQL instance, so you can actually use the same database for US and Australia.

Another solution would be to use a different approach such as deploying your application on GKE on different regions so you can have it all centralized on the same project.

I hope you find this information useful!